# Set cursor of contenteditable div after changing the innerHTML on keypress in chrome

Tags: javascript

I need to have customized spellchecker for div. Div should underline the misspelled words with red lines as in chrome when the user types a wrong word.  But on changing the innerHTML the cursor is moving to the front of the text. 
Functionality should work in chrome
Need suggestions.

```
var n = document.createElement("div");
n.id = "div_";
n.setAttribute("onkeydown", "CopyField(" + "div_" + ")");

function CopyField(sender)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        var Value = document.getElementById(sender).innerText.split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < Value.length; i++)
        {
            Value[i] = "<span class='redwiggle'>" + Value[i] + "</span>";
        }   
        var FinalValue = Value.join(' ');
        document.getElementById(sender).innerHTML = FinalValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: use DOM methods instead of innerHTML. yes, it's a pain, but you have to do it...

Comment: Is there any other DOM method except innerHTML to make the words underlined